# Angular 6: HostListener decorator broken by production build

Tags: angular, typescript, events, keyboard-events, angular-decorator

My application registers hotkey listeners to allow the user to perform actions with the keyboard only.  Here's an example:

```
  @HostListener('document:keydown.meta.a', ['$event'])
  selectAllHotkey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.nodes = this.nodes.map(node => {
      node.is_selected = true;
      return node;
    });
  }
```

This method is inside of a component, and works fine as it is.  However, more recently users have requested platform-specific hotkeys (i.e. Control instead of Command).  To accomplish this, I created the following function:

```
export function userAgentToggle<D>(window: Window, pcValue: D, osxValue: D): D {
  if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac OS X') === -1) {
    return pcValue;
  } else {
    return osxValue;
  }
}
```

All this function does is return one of two arguments based on the user agent.  I can apply it like this:

```
  @userAgentToggle(
    window,
    HostListener('document:keydown.control.a', ['$event']),
    HostListener('document:keydown.meta.a', ['$event'])
  )
  selectAllHotkey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // ...
  }
```

And this works fine in development.  Utilizing a user agent switcher, I can verify that each platform is recognized and the appropriate key is listened for.  However, it does **not** work in production.  If the application goes through the build process, then *none* of the event listeners fire.

Normally I'd assume this is a problem with my code, but the fact that it works in dev makes me think this might be a compiler bug.  Am I doing something wrong, or should I file an Angular bug ticket?

**Edit:** I tried shifting things around, and ended up getting an error that said `Function calls are not supported in decorators`.  Googling around revealed this is a constraint of the Angular AoT compiler.  I think having this kind of dynamic behavior just isn't supported by Angular's compiler.  I got around it by listening only to the `keydown` event, and adding a second decorator that can filter down to the right key combination.

Comment: Maybe I am stupid, have you tried debugging it in Chrome? Maybe you can see the difference between dev and prod.

Comment: @wannadream I have tried, but it's very difficult to do because the production build is all minified.

Comment: @Jonah is you make a sample stackblitz ill help you out

Comment: @cgatian I filed a bug ticket and created a stackblitz. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26729#issue-373608371

Comment: @Jonah awesome Ill take a look!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found: Put an event binding on keydown in a top HTML element tag
(keydown)="yourMethod($event)"

The backend remains the same(use selectAllHotkey() or any other method)

Cause: I seems ng build with --aot parameter does not work with @HostListener (from some version of Angular forward)